# iPad SDK: Why are my nib changes not showing?

Tags: iphone

I've made an iPad app. Now, I'm changing some UI elements in the NIB. When I run the app in the simulator none of my changes appear.

I've tried touching the project before building. Nothing is working.

Can anyone shed some insight?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not loading the correct NIB file, or more probably you have for gotten to make the right connections in you NIB file with the [owner file](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/04_InspectingNib.html).

If none of these are the case we are going to need some code that shows where you load you nib and/or a NIB we can inspect ourselves. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Clean the target (⇧⌘K)
- Delete the app from the Simulator
- Build & Run as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you save the changes in Interface Builder. I've found that on occasion I've forgot to save changes there, with predictable results.

Answer (score 0):

In the Simulator menu, select "Reset Content and Settings…" which wipes out anything that was there previously. Xcode saves time by not installing anything it thinks is already there. This usually works fine, but occasionally can lead to out-of-date resources not being updated.